# Happy second year anniversary....!

Tags: discussion

[image]

Happy second year anniversary folks. This is the time to pat on our backs and celebration. Still a long way to go, our [stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) still need be improved which we will do eventually.

If anybody have any kind of suggestion feel free to express yourself.  Any idea for what we should do from now onwards or anything required to be changed can freely be provided in answers.

Answer (score 8):

In order to improve the percentage of answer, overall quality of the answers and ultimately in the growth of users and site as well in terms of information and knowledge on Hinduism topics, We should recommend users to read some important Hindu scriptures that are mostly used.

We can also apply questionnaire/deliberation  on defined topics in order to encourage users to participate in Hinduism.SE

Comment: Also this site is generating around 5 questions per day which should be 10 questions per day for healthy beta.

Answer (score 0):

Namste to All . **Happy second year anniversary**  to Hinduism Stack Exchange.
And All  folks who kept the spirit alive.