# Help us out to make this site better!

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

As we know, Hinduism.SE is now two years old. It's been a great journey till now, and am looking to make it even better. I will need your help, i.e users of Hinduism.SE to make it even more better.

I've posted such questions before as well and wanted to post one more as we have new members joining Hinduism.SE family.

Talking about help, what I need from you is to use your [privileges](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) granted to you when you get x number of reputation. As your reputation increases, you are granted certain privileges by StackExchange which can be used to keep our site clean, on topic, and a good resource for one to refer to.

---

How can you use your privileges in the right way? Carry below actions to keep our community on topic, helpful, clean.

- Edit questions and answers, correct spelling errors, grammatical errors, add a reference, and so on...
- Flag spam, abusive, low quality posts so that moderators can take appropriate actions.
- Review posts in the review queue, accept edits made by other users if they are helpful
- Write canonical posts, you can answer your own questions and share your knowledge with others.
- Flag comments if users are done discussing over particular topic on a particular post.
- Help others by commenting, tell them whats wrong with their question or answer, ask them to share references. The reason we ask for references is because Hinduism is a vast topic, where one particular thing has multiple stories behind it, me or you might know whats the right one, but non hindu people looking for particular information will be confused, and we surely don't want to give that user experience when they visit our site.

So it's our responsibility as one Hinduism family to keep our site on topic, tidy, informative, helpful and interesting. Make this happen and we might get out of beta. If our site generates low quality posts every time, that day won't be far when we get a mail saying that SE is shutting down our website.

Below are the statistics am sharing with you (as of when I am writing this post), I want to see better numbers here and it is only possible if you help us out.

```
+------+--------------+
|3,325 | questions    |
|4,032 | answers      |
|70%   | answered     |
|4,189 | users        |
|5,099 | visitors/day |
+------+--------------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lets maintain some quality on the site](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/299/lets-maintain-some-quality-on-the-site)

Comment: @sv. ? Well, what?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Similar [question](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/536/2995) was closed as duplicate and there are enough [FAQs](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) here already, what's the point of yet another post?

Comment: @sv. You are either new to the site or you just don't appreciate the efforts put by others. I usually post such questions time to time to keep users updated about statistics, where they are going wrong and so on.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Only the last line of your post talks about statistics, much of your post has been covered in a ton of similar posts and FAQs here already which is why I marked it as dup. You can check my profile to know if I appreciate others' efforts or not. But I certainly appreciate users or mods who lead by example and spend more time on main site than on meta! If you want to have meaningful discussion you can ping me in chat.

Comment: @sv. Annual self evaluation doesn't looks like duplicate to me.

Comment: Thanks you, i will be participating more on meta O:)

Answer (score 11):

> If our site generates low quality posts every time, that day won't be far when we get a mail saying that SE is shutting down our website.

Above point bothered me! and if it is so, we should *surly* pay attention to it.

OK; I'll regularly **review** the [low quality questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts).

Everyone are requested to use their [moderation privileges](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation). I think reviewing & flagging are the important activity to moderate the site.

And talking about percentage of answer and user participation, I've posted [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/594/277).

Also visit couple of later suggestions:

- [Let's concentrate on "percent answered" stats!](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/643/277)
- [Consider fixing questions that will lead to opinion-based or low-quality answers](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/681/277)