# Let's concentrate on "percent answered" stats!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, unanswered-questions, suggestions

Our community/site is growing fine but it requires some attention to [unanswered questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers). From [Area51.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism), our site shows 73% answered (1098 questions with no answers) so it *needs* considerable work:

[image]

> [image]

Also visiting the list of all sites according to [percent answered](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) criteria gives an idea about our where we stand.

> [image]

You'll find Hinduism.SE among the last 16 of 150+ communities. Especially talking about `Beta` communities (as this doesn't matter much to `launched` communities) we're at 4<sup>th</sup> from the last! Other religion communities viz. Buddhism, Christianity are doing much better in this area.

---

I think we can achieve this by considering following solutions:

**Search through questions having no answers**:

Here are some tips for searching:

- Look for [unanswered](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/unanswered) questions with your skilled/favourite tags for example first go to https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered and search for your favourite tags by entering `[tag-name]` in search bar. It will show you unanswered tags as per your specified tag criteria.
- Another way is to add some tags as "Favorite Tags" from left-side bar and now you can simply click on your favourite tag while surfing through https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/unanswered. It will filter unanswered questions as per your favourite tags for example :  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/`tag-name`
- Or https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags for filtering unanswered questions based on your all favourite tags together.

This may be an *effective* way for *answering* unanswered questions in *your* skilled/favourite area!

So, I'm ***encouraging experienced and knowledgeable users*** to **consider answering** or pay attention to unanswered questions.

- Here I'm mainly addressing *experienced* users as they are familiar with StackExchange and also know how to write a good answer.
- Here I'm mainly addressing *knowledgeable* users as they have the skill and knowledge in some areas and scriptural knowledge is essential to provide canonical answers.

Following are some **suggestions** while visiting unanswered question:

- If you find question is not clear then consider to improve question by editing.
- If you find question that are either off-topic, primarily opinion based or duplicate, then consider to vote/flag for closing.

Miscellaneous:

- You can also answer to your own question. [Self-answering](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) is [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)
- On some of old questions I've found that sometimes *comments are actually answering the question or can answer the question the question if expanded or elaborated*. So, if this is the case, then try to answer the question especially when questioner reply in favourable way like that worked as answer, something like: "Thank you!, this helped me" or ["Thank you!, this is what I was looking for"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8505/who-was-the-sage-who-saw-multiple-mahabharatha-and-ramyana/16142#comment18014_8505) etc. by questioner on your comment to question.

---

This will help our community to show good performance in terms of *percentage answered* as well as help unanswered questions/users to get *quality* answers!

Thanks.

<sup>For discussions use our [chat-room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism).</sup>

Comment: Nice suggestion, but there are many questions, which are Not asked for the answer(s)!

Comment: @iammilind Hmm.. I can understand such trouble but I think we can try best for the *(possible)* questions that can be answered.

Comment: This site demands that answers should be supported from Scriptures.But,1) i don't think there is even a single user here who can be called "Sastragya" ,a person who is well versed in all Scriptures.Most of them attempt answers citing from only BG.And 2) Another requirement for the Q to be answered with Scriptural quotes is that the Q has to have some merit as well.So,the reasons for so many unanswered Q's are two fold in my view.

Comment: @Rickross similar/related discussion [About References?](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/597/277)

Comment: 72 % is answered and accepted?... or only answered questions?...

Comment: @Tezz I think Question that has no accepted or upvoted answer is considered as unanswered question.

Comment: @Tezz I think even questions with upvoted answers but no acceptance counts as unanswered.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan no. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233823/which-questions-are-considered-toward-the-percentage-of-questions-answered-for-a/233825#comment927468_233825

Comment: @Pandya many questions can be answered by comments only. The OP agrees with the answer stated in the comment. If they are posted in the answer field, the percentage gets increased. Also there are some inactive questions which should be closed.

Comment: @SreeCharan Yes, you can discuss commenter to post an answer and vote for closing questions which should be... (e.g see [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/which-hindu-texts-contains-the-story-of-santoshi-mata-and-about-her-other-legend#comment39156_5300) and [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9671/277) activities.)

Comment: It is an old thread but what i observed that most of the time many of the users here answer the question in comment or just discuss about question in comment and then disappear. if some user has his comment upvoted he should write a comprehensive answer elaborating that.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar Yes, I'm aware, look at [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/15189?m=33885672#33885672).

Comment: @Pandya I think moderators should step in and encourage for writing answers instead of chatty comments or if possible we must have low word count for commenting on this site. because if two or three comments are answering the questions why don't use wiki posts then.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar Anyway, I've just revised question including this topic.