# A question on bounties offered

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

From [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/121/pradip-gangopadhyay?tab=reputation) one can see that the user Pradip Gangopadhyay has earned a bounty of 500 points on Nov 22 that was offered by user sv. And, for the same answer he earned a bounty of another 500 points today (offered by the same user sv).

Even now, [the question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2816/4732) has a bounty on it worth 500 points (offered by the same user sv) that expires in 7 days. The bounty message says "Reward Pradip Gangopadhyay's excellent answer from the initial days of the site when it was possible to write such answers without repercussions."

So, the same user Pradip is set to receive another 500 points within seven days for the same answer and from the same user sv.

And the same is happening with another question.

This [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26670/4732) has already received a bounty worth 500 points offered by user sv. But at present a bounty is active on the [same question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26646/4732) offered again by the same user sv.

The bounty message says "Reward zaxebo1's answer which quotes Vivekananda's views on Smṛtis and Purāṇas.". That means the same user zaxebo1 is all set to receive  another 500 points for the same answer from the same user.

Can someone please tell me what's going on here? I am unable to understand. It seems that the user (sv) is offering same answers bounties worth 500 points over and over again?

Comment: I think.. that is fine.

Comment: Like @Mr_Green said nothing wrong with it. If a user feels that some answers from certain user should be awarded, they can put bounty. Infact I too offered bounty to good answers couple of times. Sure my offered bounty was very less, but yeah! :D

Comment: It is not fine. Not because points should not be donated. But why this entire 7 days wait and 500 points at a time. Can't it be done in one go ? It is a bit annoying to see the same question in "bountied" tab for days at a stretch

Comment: Maybe they are trying to utilize the bounty period as much as possible for more views/traffic. IMHO, we shouldn't be annoyed by this. I understand the same user is about to get the bounty again but if anyone has a better answer they should post it or move on.

Comment: @Mr_Green - it is not about better answer. IMO this can drive away potential new members because they will see the same question in bountied tab like forever. What is the motivation here ? SV is not looking for a new answer. There is an existing answer and he wants to reward it. So why not do it in one go and be done with it .

Comment: Maybe some mods can clarify this action or SV himself. My understanding, I don't see anything wrong with it at all. `this can drive away potential new members because they will see the same question in bountied tab like forever` - this looks highly unlikely to me. Let's wait ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: "There is an existing answer and he wants to reward it." --- Rewarding an answer that you are impressed with is fine. But here something really weird is happening. It's seemingly an endless process of rewarding. 500 points awarded thrice already (1500 in total). If it happens 7 times or 10 times or 20 times will that be "fine" even then? @Carmensandiego

Comment: Ofcourse not. If you read my comment in entirety, I'm not in favor of this modus operandi. Also it seems from main meta that there is precedence of such a case wherein bounties were reversed and post was locked. Suggest the same be done here

Comment: Yes I know that you are not saying that what's happening is fine but some says that it is @Carmensandiego

Comment: Though it might feel a bit weird it is fine, IMO again :D. For example see this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278242/196352. I feel we should not observe the actions of users in such detail. _people are uniquely weird_. Let's wait and see how this evolves. For now, looks ok to me.

Comment: @Mr_Green - please elaborate on what you mean by "how this evolves". After how many repetitions will you change your opinion? How did you arrive at this number ?

Comment: I might not consider the repetitions at all. I meant evolve by If the post got a good answer and satisfies the OP or the community decides the post is off-topic and lock it or if somehow we sensed that the user is just trolling. Mere repetitions won't consider it as trolling but other actions could maybe.

Comment: @Mr_Green - An answer is already accepted by querist. So "waiting for a better answer" is not really applicable. The only question is when will the moderators step in to lock the post and stop this charade.

Comment: From your comments I got the doubt whether you are aware of what is actually going on here .. @Mr_Green Nobody is looking for a better or new or canonical answer here.Neither is anybody trying to highlight the post so that it gets the due attention. Here the motive is entirely something else.

Comment: @Carmen about mods: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56321324#56321324

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - yes, i read that. Assume you have pinged Pandya in chat as suggested by him

Comment: I feel users should have the opportunity to award bounties multiple times, though ideally no one would go insane with bounties like this. Here however things are a bit different, the intention is not to award multiple bounties (no one will say it openly but here goes) - the user is no doubt a great respectable and knowledgeable user, but he seems to have been hauled up for something and suspended. Here the motive is to highlight to the community (clearly mentions in the reasons for the bounty) the superiority of modern/ western ideologies that are contradictory to the tenets of Sanatana Dharma

Comment: Archit, I agree with you. Though it is our understanding, we don't know what SV thinks of this. On this site, if one shows/highlighting their beliefs we have two options either to ignore it or take action. I am with ignoring it as I don't want to drag this around and make it more ugly. I strongly urge all to keep their beliefs to themselves and not bring on this site.

Answer (score 4):

So as per the comments exchanged between sv. and me, it seems he *may be* wanting to award 5000 worth bounty rep to that answer which is not possible to do so at one go.

> @sv. Can we send award bounty as many times as we want? – [TheLittleNaruto Nov 30 at 8:20](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/does-science-contradict-hinduism-how-to-deal-with-scientific-discoveries-that-d?noredirect=1#comment135413_2816)

> Yes, in increasing amounts until you hit the max bounty of 500. If I think a particular answer is worth 5000 points, I have to award the bounty at least 10 times. @TheLittleNaruto – [sv. 11 hours ago](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/does-science-contradict-hinduism-how-to-deal-with-scientific-discoveries-that-d?noredirect=1#comment135498_2816)

But in general sense it is highly unlikely even a high rep user like him would lose that much rep for any answer. If he really wants to motivate users, though he is free to award bounty to an answer which looks best to him; but my suggestion would be to help  in Pandya's initiative: [Monthly Answer Challenge: Answer old unanswered questions!](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/monthly-answer-challenge-answer-old-unanswered-questions)

Otherwise it doesn't make sense to give that many bounty rep "to a single answer" and that too is coming from an old privileged user like him. If this goes on further, best is to lock the question as already mentioned in [@Mr_Green's answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2048/647)

Also one more point which can be noticed here that this unusual behavior he started showing right after his ban got over.

Comment: The answer by Mr. Pradip existed since Aug 2014, the user sv is fully aware of it's existence all these years and all of a sudden the thought came that I should award it thousands of points and that too after something happened with the him? And we are all kids not to understand what's going on? Also why only 5000 why not 24,000? If that amount is possible to donate the drama definitely ends there :P.

Comment: `And we are all kids not to understand what's going on?` I might be naive, what is actually going on? [Here is what I actually think going on](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56323148#56323148)

Comment: @Mr_Green - I find it hard to believe that you don't know whats going on even after your chat with TheLittleNaruto on this topic, and this answer. To be clear, its absolutely fine if sv wants to donate 5k or 24k. But please don't subject the rest of the community to see this post for 10 weeks or 48 weeks  in bounty tab. Get it done and over with. But if it cannot be done with one shot then lock the post

Comment: It is not a blocker if it is visible in the bounty tab. It is not like it is holding the whole page or blocking the page by any means. It just a single post! even if there are multiple posts, the user can always scroll or sort them. Locking the post for being on top always and finding it as an annoyance for some people, looks overkill to me. It is clearly against SE policy. Again, if you want to lock the post for being a personal annoyance then that is wrong. If you want to lock the post because it is off-topic then we should have that discussion on another meta post.

Comment: @Mr_Green - If you believe that a post being awarded bounties by the same person consecutively for a period of 10 weeks to 48 weeks is in line with SE community standards and guidelines then I have nothing more to add.

Comment: I don't care why sv is behaving this way, whether he was rightfully banned etc. We can't control reaction choice of others. The question being asked is whether community is okay with a particular answer getting bounty award by the same person repeatedly for a period of 10 to 48 weeks

Answer (score 2):

The actions of user SV looks completely fine to me, though they are unnecessary.

As stated in [improvements to bounty system](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/19/improvements-to-bounty-system/):

> Well, I’m happy to announce that we’re improving the bounty system to address (almost) all of these issues. As of now:
>
> - Any user with sufficient reputation can start a bounty on any question
> - **A question may have multiple bounties**, though only one active bounty is allowed at any given time.
> - **Bounty awards are no longer tied to accepted answer in any way**.

The case would have been different if:

- The post is pretty well stable already (*No better new answer can be posted*)
- The post is off-topic.
- There is no place for improvements

In such a case, the best solution would be to lock the post. [Here is a related incident](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91814/196352).

Comment: Seems like there is precedence of question getting locked and bounty being refunded. That makes sense.

Comment: In that case is it worth to flag the question post for the same treatment?

Comment: If all agree so. IMO, those two posts seem on topic and open for good answers.

Comment: @Mr_Green In that case we shall wait for responses from other fellow users.