# Consider fixing questions that will lead to opinion-based or low-quality answers

Tags: discussion, post-quality, editing, suggestions

Recently, I found that the *nature* of some questions *leads to* answers:

- that are opinion-based or
- that deviate too much from OP's title or main question or
- that are of very low quality

So, I'm encouraging experienced users to **improve** or **fix** such questions.

These problematic questions may contain some content or topics that should be [avoided](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). So, we can improve the question by removing or fixing such parts of the question.

I'm not saying improve every other question (though it's better if you've time) or the whole question, but I'm mainly talking about questions (or their parts) that you think can be easily fixed to make the question more acceptable for the site.

In brief, **the objective is** to fix the deviated part of question (that can potentially lead to debate) so that the question now becomes more specific, on-topic and clear.

From Help Center:

> - Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date.<sup>[1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/editing)</sup>
> - Last but not least, [edit and improve](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) the existing questions and answers! By doing these things, you are helping keep Stack Exchange a great place to share knowledge of our craft.<sup>[2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)</sup>

Experienced and 1K+ users: Please use your [moderation privileges](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)!

Note: Also consider to **vote/flag** for closing if question doesn't fit for this site.

---

Following the above will ultimately enhance the overall quality of our site with good Q & A.

Thanks.